# Time based container scheduling on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

What is the recommended way to execute a container or pod based on a time-based schedule?  For example, a task to run at 2am for 10 minutes every day.

On a traditional linux server, crontab would easily work, and that obviously still is possible inside the container.  However, since this task only executes for 10 minutes I was looking for a mechanism to execute a basic container on a given time interval, then dispose of of the container.

Chronos (part of Mesos) appears to have a similar behavior, is this possible in Container Engine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is expected to be supported in 1.3: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/11980

UPDATE:

> didn't meet the 1.3 deadline so it'll sleep into 1.4

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2156#issuecomment-223385808

UPDATE (thanks @Kevinoid):
Looks like it has reached alpha in 1.4 and progress is now being tracked in https://github.com/kubernetes/features/issues/19 with usage documentation at http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/cron-jobs/

Comment: This has been moved to 1.4 https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2156#issuecomment-223385808

Comment: Looks like it has reached alpha in 1.4 and progress is now being tracked in https://github.com/kubernetes/features/issues/19 with usage documentation at http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/cron-jobs/

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there isn't currently support for cron jobs in Kubernetes or Container Engine. The Github Issue tracking it is [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/2156), if you'd like to share ideas for what features it should have or express your interest in it!

Answer (score 3):

A work around for now would be to use a run-once Pod and add kubectl to your cron tab on a machine.

e.g. add

```
kubectl create -f <run-once-pod>
```

to your cron tab.

Comment: To clarify, getting a pod to run only once, this would be the restartPolicy: Never?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like "Cron Jobs" (since 1.4) is the answer: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/cron-jobs/

Answer (score 0):

As noted, this was added as part of K8s 1.4 and [here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/cron-jobs/) is the official documentation.  (moved url updated)